# expo-skia: filter an image and apply color overlay

Tags: expo, skia

I'm trying to use `expo-skia` to saturate an image and then apply an `rgba` color overlay above it. I took the saturation matrix from the `pixi` sources and it works fine. I can't understand how to add a color overlay after filtering.

My code:

```
import {
  BlendColor,
  ColorMatrix,
  Group,
  Image
} from '@shopify/react-native-skia'
...
<Group>
  <BlendColor color={color} mode='srcOver' />
  <Image fit='cover' image={skiaImageSource} rect={rect}>
    <ColorMatrix matrix{matrix} />
  </Image>
</Group>
```

gives me a saturated image but without any overlay.
If I remove `<ColorMatrix matrix{matrix} />` I see my overlay above the image, but the image isn't saturated of course.

The package versions I'm using:

```
"expo": "^46.0.0"
@shopify/react-native-skia": "0.1.141"
```

Could anyone help, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

```
...
const canvas = useRef<SkiaView>()
const [filteredImage, setFilteredImage] = useState<SkImage>()
...
useEffect(() => {
    let timerId = setTimeout(function makeSnapshot() {
      if (!canvas.current) {
        timerId = setTimeout(makeSnapshot, MAKE_SNAPSHOT_TIMEOUT_MS)

        return
      }

      try {
        setFilteredImage(canvas.current.makeImageSnapshot())
      } catch {
        timerId = setTimeout(makeSnapshot, MAKE_SNAPSHOT_TIMEOUT_MS)
      }
    }, MAKE_SNAPSHOT_TIMEOUT_MS)

    return () => clearTimeout(timerId)
  }, [])
...
return filteredImage ? (
    <Canvas style={canvasStyle}>
      <Rect rect={imageRect}>
        <BlendColor color={overlayColor} mode='srcOver' />
        <ImageShader fit='cover' image={filteredImage} rect={imageRect} />
        {getFilters()}
      </Rect>
    </Canvas>
  ) : (
    <Canvas ref={canvas} style={canvasStyle}>
      <Image fit='cover' image={image} rect={imageRect}>
        <ColorMatrix matrix={getSaturationMatrix()} />
      </Image>
    </Canvas>
  )
```